# How to use regexp_replace in spark.sql() to extract hashtags from string

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, regex-replace

I need to write a `regexg_replace` query in `spark.sql()` and I'm not sure how to handle it. For readability purposes, I have to utilize SQL for it. I am trying to pull out the hashtags from the table. I know how to do this using the python method but most of my team are SQL users.

My dataframe example looks like so:

| Insta_post |
| --- |
| Today, Senate Dems vote to #SaveTheInternet. Proud to support similar #NetNeutrality legislation here in the House… |
| RT @NALCABPolicy: Meeting with @RepDarrenSoto . Thanks for taking the time to meet with @LatinoLeader ED Marucci Guzman. #NALCABPolicy2018.… |
| RT @Tharryry: I am delighted that @RepDarrenSoto will be voting for the CRA to overrule the FCC and save our #NetNeutrality rules. Find out… |

My code:

I create a tempview:

```
post_df.createOrReplaceTempView("post_tempview")

post_df = spark.sql("""
select
regexp_replace(Insta_post, '.*?(.|'')(#)(\w+)', '$1') as a 
from post_tempview
where Insta_post like '%#%'
""")
```

My end result:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|a                                                                                                                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Today, Senate Dems vote to #SaveTheInternet. Proud to support similar #NetNeutrality legislation here in the House…  |
|RT @NALCABPolicy: Meeting with @RepDarrenSoto . Thanks for taking the time to meet with @LatinoLeader ED Marucci Guzman. #NALCABPolicy2018.…|
|RT @Tharryry: I am delighted that @RepDarrenSoto will be voting for the CRA to overrule the FCC and save our #NetNeutrality rules. Find out…|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

desired result:

```
+---------------------------------+
|a                                |
+---------------------------------+
| #SaveTheInternet, #NetNeutrality|
| #NALCABPolicy2018               |
| #NetNeutrality                  |
+---------------------------------+
```

I haven't really used `regexp_replace` too much so this is new to me. Any help would be appreciated as well as an explanation of how to structure the subsets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spark **3.1+**, you can use [`regexp_extract_all`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_extract_all) function to extract multiple matches:

```
post_df = spark.sql("""
    select  regexp_extract_all(Insta_post, '(#\\\\w+)', 1) as a 
    from    post_tempview
    where   Insta_post like '%#%'
""")

post_df.show(truncate=False)
#+----------------------------------+
#|a                                 |
#+----------------------------------+
#|[#SaveTheInternet, #NetNeutrality]|
#|[#NALCABPolicy2018]               |
#|[#NetNeutrality]                  |
#+----------------------------------+
```

---

For Spark **<3.1**, you can use `regexp_replace` to remove all that doesn't match the hashtag pattern :

```
post_df = spark.sql("""
select  trim(trailing ',' from regexp_replace(Insta_post, '.*?(#\\\\w+)|.*', '$1,')) as a 
from    post_tempview
where   Insta_post like '%#%'
""")

post_df.show(truncate=False)
#+-------------------------------+
#|a                              |
#+-------------------------------+
#|#SaveTheInternet,#NetNeutrality|
#|#NALCABPolicy2018              |
#|#NetNeutrality                 |
#+-------------------------------+
```

Note the use `trim` to remove the unnecessary trailing commas created by the first replace `$,`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a view? Because the following code might do it:

```
df = df.filter(F.col('Insta_post').like('%#%'))
col_trimmed = F.trim((F.regexp_replace('Insta_post', '.*?(#\w+)|.+', '$1 ')))
df = df.select(F.regexp_replace(col_trimmed,'\s',', ').alias('a'))
df.show(truncate=False)

#     +--------------------------------+
#     |a                               |
#     +--------------------------------+
#     |#SaveTheInternet, #NetNeutrality|
#     |#NALCABPolicy2018               |
#     |#NetNeutrality                  |
#     +--------------------------------+
```

I ended up using two of `regexp_replace`, so potentially there could be a better alternative, just couldn't think of one.